# How to use DBA centroid in tsclust with hierarchical clustering

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, centroid, dtw, tsclust

I'm pretty new to R and try to do some time series clustering.

I use the function `tsclust` and want to combine the `dtwbasic` distance with the `dba` centroid in hierarchical clustering.

However, when I try to do so I receive the error

> "The 'centroid' argument was provided but it wasn't a function, so it
>   was ignored."

I use the following code:

```
> cluster.dtw.h_1.d <-list()
> for (i in 2:10)
{
  cluster.dtw.h_1.d[[i]] <- tsclust(mydata, type = "h", k = i,  distance = "dtw_basic", centroid = "dba",control = hierarchical_control(method = "complete"), seed = 390, preproc = NULL, args = tsclust_args(dist = list(window.size =30L)))
}
```

Could anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: You need to pass centroid as a function, so `centroid = dba` (no quotes).

Comment: Can't believe it's that easy ... thank you so much!